# How to implement a proper login system for an application where other applications can access a particular service?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, user-management

I am developing a movie ticket selling application in asp.net core where a registered user can buy tickets. There are some other applications which can insert new movie ticket in ticket selling application.

1. How to implement a proper login system for the other applications and give them access for a service?
2. How to manage customers and other applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your needs, you might want to take a look  at Token based authentication with OAUTH 2.0. Second option would be [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) .